# How to search for a specific column data using a variable and update its column data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

What I'm trying to do:  I'm trying to change a specific column under the 'username' row where the username is the same as `$loginuser` var and change the `speedrunhighscore` row in that column into a new `speedruhighscore`.

The problem:
in the code below there is a line in which I put in bold, and that's the line I'm trying to run to change the data in my database but nothing changes in my database but the echos are all running smoothly.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "smolgames";

    $speedrunhighscore = $_POST["speedrunhighscore"];
    $loginuser = $_POST["loginuser"];

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM userinfos WHERE username = '" . $loginuser . "'"; 
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){        
      **$sql3 = "UPDATE userinfos SET speedrunhighscore = (' . $speedrunhighscore . ') WHERE username = '" . $loginuser . "'";**
      echo "updating your new highscore":

                if($conn->query($sql3) === TRUE){
                    echo "your highscore have been updated successfully!";

                }
                else{
                    echo "Error: ". $sql3 . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
                }
    } 
    else{
        echo "no usernames found";

        if($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE){
            echo "new highscore send successfully";
        }
        else{
            echo "Error: ". $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
        }
    }   

    $conn->close();
?>
```

note: the variable `loginuser` changes from a string I post using unity C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you should be using prepared statements with bounded placeholders. This ensures your query is not vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and ensures that even usernames such as `O'Riley` would work.

Next up, you don't need to check if the row exists before updating it -- you can just attempt to perform the update right away, and check how many rows was in fact updated.

Lastly, you should be configuring your MySQLi connection to throw exceptions on error, this means that you don't have to do individual error handling for each and every query.

```php
<?php
// Configure MySQLi to throw exceptions on failure instead 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "smolgames";

$speedrunhighscore = $_POST["speedrunhighscore"];
$loginuser = $_POST["loginuser"];

try {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE userinfos
                                SET speedrunhighscore = ?
                                WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $speedrunhighscore, $loginuser);
    $stmt->execute();
    $affectedRows = $stmt->affected_rows;
    $stmt->close();
    
    if ($affectedRows) {
        echo "your highscore have been updated successfully!";
    } else {
        echo "no usernames found";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle the exception 
    // Log it, send a message to the user "something went wrong"
}
```

You should be implementing some sort of authentication and authorization layer, as now you can just submit someone else's username with any arbitrary highscore, and you can basically update any scores in the table.